# Philosopher's Stone or not on Jungle Udyr?

Tags: league-of-legends

I use Udyr quite a lot in the jungle and usually start build boots+3 then Heart of Gold. After that should I build Philosopher's Stone for more gold, or go straight for my normal build (Wit's End / Randuin's Omen, etc.). I've seen both Philosopher's Stone and non-Philosopher's Stone done.

Answer (score 4):

Udyr's farming is so good that you really don't need a Philosopher's Stone to keep up with others, just the Heart of Gold will do. What I usually do is go boots+3 pots and then Heart of Gold, Wit's End, and then Randuin's Omen. Once there, you can build whatever you really want (for me it's usually Fratmogs).

Comment: Can you explain what Fratmogs stands for for people who aren't familiar with the term?

Comment: Fratmogs is Frozen Mallet, Atmas Impaler, and Warmogs Armour. It's a very powerful combination because it gives a very large amount of Health, which in turn causes large amounts of Attack Damage from the passive on Atmas Impaler, and the slow from Frozen Mallet helps for chasing.

Comment: Good answer. Udyr's turtle compensate for mana if you are too much low. and HoG gives the gold.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the Philosopher's Stone really necessary on any other junglers. If you're getting counterjungled though, the extra gold is nice.

Basically, if you're jungling like a boss, forget about Philosopher's Stone.
If you need the extra boost, then Philosopher's Stone is awesome.

:) Have fun in the jungle!

Answer (score 0):

All depends on how you want to play someone. You can test out builds and see what fits you best. Personally I've seen Udyr grab a Wriggle's Lantern instead of gold per 5 items.

Answer (score 0):

I would get it if I were going top lane, but with the jungle Udyr, not really. I prefer going for Mercury's Treads, Heart of Gold, Wit's End... Keep in mind, Wit's End will be your biggest item, damage-wise, until late game.

Answer (score -1):

Philosopher's Stone is a NO on Udyr jungle